# MessageTransformation exception during error handling in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a http inboundgateway and defined an error channel to the gateway .

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
    request-channel="requestChannel"  reply-channel="replyChannel" 
        supported-methods="POST" request-payload-type="com.test.RequestWsDTO"
    path="/trips/modify" error-channel="errorChannel" >
    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

From the gateway , it goes to a transformer to transform the message to an appropriate request for ws outboundgateway

```
<int:transformer id="segmentCancelTransformer" ref="segmentCancelTransformerBean" input-channel="segmentCancelChannel"
             method="transform" output-channel="rcsChannel"/>
    <beans:bean id="segmentCancelTransformerBean" class="com.test.SegmentCancelRequestTransformer" />
```

I throw a runtime exception from the Transformer .

I have defined an service activator to handle the exception

```
   <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="exceptionhandler" method="createErrorResponse"/>
<beans:bean id="exceptionTransformer" class="com.test.ExceptionHandler" />
```

In the ExceptionHandler class , I am handling the exception like

```
public  ErrorDTO createErrorResponse(ErrorMessage msg) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured "+msg.getPayload());
        ErrorDTO dto=new ErrorDTO ();
      ......................
```

msg.getPayload() is showing the exception to be of "org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException"

Exception message stacktrace:

```
Exception occured org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: You're doing absolutely right. But what is the question? Maybe you're really should look inside that nested exception for answer?.. please, rephrase your problem and explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: If I am throwing any custom exception , I am always getting MessageTransformationException and the thrown exception is coming in nested exception part . I don't think that is correct .I should be getting some exception of type MessageHandlingException. Isnt it ?

As per my understanding , the  custom exception is not getting properly transformed  in Error channel  , hence always giving a transformation exception . 
I want to know if i have missed anything ?

Answer (score 0):

That's really correct and also useful. First, you deal with messaging where the loosely-coupling is the first of principles between components. Another advantage is the `failedMessage` set to the property of the `MessagingException` which you can use to determine the problem.

Since the error maybe from another thread, it's hard to determine what's wrong by just a custom exception. Anyway you always can find your own cause in the stack trace.

Comment: thanks . My concern here is why it is giving MessageTransformationException  instead of MessageHandlingException .

Exception occured org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException:


I know both are of type MessagingException , but I have to traverse 3 layers down the stack trace to find the actual exception thrown . 
Also isn't  MessageHandlingException different from MessageTransformationException ?

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. I think the POJO method invoker doesn't know about transformer context, so, it throws `MessageHandlingException` as is. The transformer, in its turn, throws the exception according its logic. You might be right and we can reconsider do not throw MessageHandling if the target exception is Runtime. Please, raise a JIRA and we'll think what to do

Comment: Thanks Artem , Created a Jira ticket .